# Magento2 REST API/GraphQl for Multiple Shipping

Tags: magento2, rest-api, graphql, multishipping

I'm Creating PWA Website and I don't find any API for multi-shipping (Ship to Multiple Addresses).

I have checked Grapql on Magento's doc https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/set-shipping-address.html#syntaxpage but there is no option to set the address for each item.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ? Actually I also need an API to add multiple shipping address.

Comment: I'm working on custom module to achieve this task

Comment: @Arunendra did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there is a GraphQL endpoint in core Magento that allows you to define multiple shipping addresses on a given cart. The core `setShippingAddressesOnCart` mutation does NOT allow multiple addresses, confirmed in the resolver class `\Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Cart\SetShippingAddressesOnCart::execute`

```php
if (count($shippingAddressesInput) > 1) {
    throw new GraphQlInputException(
        __('You cannot specify multiple shipping addresses.')
    );
}
```

Looks like this feature was dropped by the Magento dev team due to low priority. I can see that a PR was raised for GraphQL multi-shipping however:

- https://github.com/magento/graphql-ce/pull/237

Looks like you will have to build this resolver yourself, the PR linked above should serve as a solid starting point.